# retrieve numbers with 0 for a single int value

Tags: scripting, function

In my script, I need to get a `0` for numbers <=9. When the user types any number, I add 5 to it and if the result is less than 9, I need to print a 0 in order to have a 2-digit number (like 07,08,09 etc.).

I wrote a function for this, but the script keeps returning thr same number "0?" over and over again in a loop.

My script:

```
echo "Hora: "

read hora

Hora=$((hora+05))

Change () {
if [ $Hora -le 9 ]; then sed -e 's/^/0'$Hora'/'; return $Hora; fi
}

Change

echo -e "$Hora"
```

***output:***

```
~$ bash test.sh
Hora:
4

09

09

09

09

09
```

Comment: Are you writing this script in bash?

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your script, but the main one is that you aren't giving any input to your `sed` command. If you just run `sed 's/foo/bar/'`, then `sed` will expect input from [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) and will continue to run each time you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Since it is getting no input but a newline from you (when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you are sending a blank line which is just a `\n` character), it will apply the script to that input. Here, you are telling it to add a `0$Hora` to the beginning of the line so that's what it does.

There are other problems in your code. For one thing, you don't need to `return()` anything since you're working on a global variable. In fact, you don't even need `sed` here, you can simply concatenate in the shell itself. Here's a working version of your script:

```bash
## It is good practice to have the functions at the beginning
## of your script.
Change () {
        if [ $Hora -le 9 ]; then
                Hora="0$Hora"
        fi
}

echo "Hora: "
read hora

Hora=$((hora+05))

Change

printf ":$Hora"
```

Note that in the simple case you show, using a function is pointless. Functions are usually used to repeat an operation multiple times at different points of the script. If all you need to do is print a `0` if the number is less than 10, you could just use `printf` itself:

```bash
printf "Hora: "
read Hora
printf '%0.2d' "$Hora"
```

Finally, you might also want to consider adding some tests to make sure your users give valid input. See [How Do I Test If A Variable Is A Number In Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash)